# How to authenticate users using GET request in FastAPI?

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi

I am new to APIs and I need to be able to authenticate users using a `GET` request, in order to automate processes in airflow.

Is it possible to authenticate using `GET` request? For example:

```
hhtp://localhost:8000/transformar?user:password
```

Answer (score 6):

In general, it is a very bad idea to do password authentication in a `GET` request. The obvious reason is that you have the `username` and `password` in the URL params (after `?`).

The standard way of doing it is having a login API something like
`POST` `http://localhost:8000/login` and provide the `username` and `password` in `form-data`. When you authenticate the user, you can return a token. This can be an API Key of a `JWT` token, etc.

Now, using this token you want to send any following requests. So, in the next `GET` request, place this token in your header under `"Authentication"`. Once you verify the token, you can return response data or, otherwise, raise a `403 Unauthorised` error.

FastAPI provides proper documentation on how to implement this [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/).